# Android studio - avd crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

i'm using android studio in windows server 2016 and have next problem: for work task i need to start android device emulation. On windows 10 emulator works fine, but same steps on windows server cause problem -"the emulator process for AVD_Pixel3A was killed". What should i do?
p.s: hyper-V components not installed, virtualization is accessable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to to have the H-visuals turned on.. Also check to see that you have HAX installed. Also be sure to turn on developer mode within the computer... I would also run the program on a physical android device to see if you get the same issue.

Also if none of these work you might have to check to see if the server runs the minimum requirements. If it does you may have to reinstall Android Studio. I had this happened to me the other day. I uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and it fixed the issue.

Comment: HAXM is installed, developer mode is on, H-visuals must be turned off, because HAXM can't start with Hyper-v components 'on'. I already reinstalled studio twice and already tried studio beta version, minimal requirments satisfied - 8gb RAM, 4 cores( in my case is 4 cores of Xeon e5), 100gb hard drive. nothing helped. On windows 10 it works, but for my work task i need to start this on win server 2016